# Python 2.7 - return list from list of lists where sub-list item contains certain character

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a long list of lists, 'persons' like this:

```
persons = [['Boris', 'Jones', '988991'], ['Charlie', 'Smith', '999'], ['Sue', 'White', '9']]
```

I want to extract from 'persons' the persons whose number only contains permitted characters:

```
permitted = ['9']
```

Result should be like this:

```
result = [['Charlie', 'Smith', '999'], ['Sue', 'White', '9']]
```

Here is what I have tried. Obviously it doesn't work :(

```
permitted = ['9']

persons = [['Boris', 'Jones', '98991'], ['Charlie', 'Smith', '999'], ['Sue', 'White', '9']]

persons = [x for x in persons if x[field][-1] in permitted]
persons = [x for x in persons if x[field][-2] in permitted]
persons = [x for x in persons if x[field][-3] in permitted]
persons = [x for x in persons if x[field][-4] in permitted]
persons = [x for x in persons if x[field][-5] in permitted]
persons = [x for x in persons if x[field][-6] in permitted]
```

The number field can contain from 1 to 6 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that as:

```
result = [i for i in persons if all(j in permitted for j in i[-1])]
```

#### Example

```
persons = [['Boris', 'Jones', '988991'], ['Charlie', 'Smith', '999'], ['Sue', 'White', '9']]
permitted = ['9']

result = [i for i in persons if all(j in permitted for j in i[-1])]

>>> print result
[['Charlie', 'Smith', '999'], ['Sue', 'White', '9']]
```

Hope that helps.

Here, the `all(...)` only evaluates to `True` if all the characters in the string are in `permitted` other `False`